# cake console 2.2.1: Bake errors

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-bake

OSX machine running MAMP. CakePHP 2.2.1 installed and configured properly (meaning that I have all green bars when I browse to the Index.php file, I have completed the Blogs tutorial and am working on my second app with which scaffolding is up and running). Now I am trying to Bake for the first time.

Per the cookbook (and others), I installed a fresh copy of cake into a directory (my users directory) and then put the path variable in my .bash_profile file 
    `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/p_scott/cake221/app/Console"`
after which I was able to go into Terminal, type  `cake` and have the console come up. You can see that up to that point, I was invoking the console from the app directory.

I first tried running `cake bake` from the terminal using the -app parameter and designating the path to my practice apps. The first time I did this, I got the following

```
    Welcome to CakePHP v2.2.1 Console
    -------------
    App : app
    Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/app/
    ------------- 
    Interactive Bake Shell
    --------------- 
    [D]atabase Configuration
    [M]odel
    [V]iew
    [C]ontroller
    [P]roject
    [F]ixture
    [T]est case
    [Q]uit
    What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)
    > c
    -------------------- 
    Bake Controller
    Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/app/Controller/
    -------------------- 
    \Use Database Config: (default/test)
    [default] >
```

No matter what I put in for the database (if I leave it blank, it asks me again), but any answer gives me the following error:

```
    Warning Error: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in    [/Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 149]

    Error: Database connection "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" is missing, or could not be created.
    #0 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(260): Mysql->connect()
    #1 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(101): DboSource->__construct(Array)
    #2 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(906): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
    #3 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(396): ModelTask->getAllTables('default')
    #4 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(419): ControllerTask->listAll(NULL)
    #5 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(136): ControllerTask->getName()
    #6 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(61): ControllerTask->_interactive()
    #7 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Command/BakeShell.php(113): ControllerTask->execute()
    #8 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(393): BakeShell->main()
    #9 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(201): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
    #10 /Users/p_scott/cake221/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
    #11 /Users/p_scott/cake221/app/Console/cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
    #12 {main}
```

Once I started getting this error, I tried navigating in terminal to the `<cake install dir>/app/Console` folder and the `<different instance of cake install dir>/app/Console` folder to try the console from within my app/s.  I either get the same errors or it asks me different questions, like:

```
    What is the path to the project you want to bake?  
    [/Users/p_scott/myapp] > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/history/app 
    What is the path to the directory layout you wish to copy?  
    [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/history/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel] >
```

PHP CLI is installed and it appears to be working

```
    PHP 5.3.8 (cli) (built: Dec  5 2011 21:24:09) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
     Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

My PDO support appears to be enabled. In terminal I typed:

```
    php --ri pdo
    PDO
    PDO support => enabled
    PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite, sqlite2
```

I don't have a php.ini file in Apache (because I am on a Mac), but the one in the PHP 5.36 directory, I have the following extensions enabled:

```
    extension=imap.so
    extension=yaz.so
    extension=mcrypt.so
    extension=gettext.so
    extension=pgsql.so
    extension=pdo_pgsql.so
    extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

After taking a break, I found an article 
(http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/31/freshly-baked-cake2-0-tips/) that talks about a change of console location in 2.0. I should try using it from that location (`<cake installed dir>/lib/Cake/Console` ). Once I tried this, I either got the questions about what layout I wanted to use or... ONCE, I was able to get the bake application to ask me to create a database configuration. I went through the steps and it pooped out this error at the end:

`Fatal error: Class 'DATABASE_CONFIG' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/history/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/DbConfigTask.php on line 264`

Which leads me to one more piece of info. This is my default DB configuration in the `<cake installation dir>/history/app/Config/database.php` file.

```
    class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'cakeHistoryUser',
    'password' => 'cakeHistoryPassword',
    'database' => 'cake_history',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
   );
```

Before posting this question (and all of this information), I spend some quality time out here and it seems like most of my issues are or CLI related but I just don't see where I need to change something and hours and hours later, I need some help.

Help me Obi Wan, you are my only hope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to interact with the database via the command line, however the PHP-CLI is a different install than the one proveided by MAMP so it doesn't know about the database server.

Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in your `app/Config/database.php` file and that should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that and it worked right away!  Thanks!!  I can't believe that it was such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this happened to me, and the easiest way I found to make it work which I don't see here is changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 and adding the port number at the end, e.g., MAMP uses port number 8899, so:

"mysql:host=127.0.0.1:8889"